# Doctrine entity custom getter

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, model, dql

How can I make this example happen? There is no relation between a Garage en red Cars. There is only a relation between a Garage en Cars.
I known I can use a repository for this, but in fact I want a getter in the Garage which will return only red cars. I assume DQL will be part of the awnser.

```
$myFavoriteCars = $myGarage->getRedCars();

Garage.php:
---------------------------
@OneToMany(...Car...)
private $cars

public function getCars()
{
    return $this->cars;
}

public function getRedCars()
{
    // How to receive only the red cars?
    // Some DQL in here?
}


Car.php:
-------------------------
@ManyToOne(...Garage...)
private $garage

private $color
```

Thank you.
Richard

Comment: you should not have data access logic within your entities. It breaks Separation of concerns,  makes Testing harder, and won't help maintainability. Your Data Acces Layer and Domain layer should be separated. That's what repositories are for.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is impossible.

I would suggest to create a specific repository for your Garage entity by adding the @ORM\Entity line to Garage.php:

```
/**
 * Garage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="garages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GarageRepository")
 */
class Garage
```

And then create a new folder called Repository in your bundle and create GarageRepository.php inside that folder. The file could look like the example bellow.

```
<?php    
namespace AppBundle\Repository;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Class GarageRepository
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Repository
 */
class GarageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * finds one or more cars with a specific color
     *
     * @param string|int $color Could be a string like 'red' or and enumeration like Color::red which translate to an
     *                          integer or the id from a color if the colors are in the database.
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function findCarsByColor($color)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
                    ->where('g.color = :color')
                    ->setParameter('color', $color)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Or a shorter solution could be adding `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Garage')->findBy(['color' => 'red']);` in your controller. This way you don't have to create a separate repository class because doctrine will use the default one. But in all cases you try to access data through doctrine you'll need some kind of repository.

Comment: Using a repository is what I try to avoid. AFAIK your repository will return red Garages. I think CarRepository::getByGarageAndColor(Garage, color) can do the trick. Unfortunately it is not the solution i'm looking for. The 'indexBy' solution is what i'm going to investigate. Thanks for thinking though.

Comment: updated my answer made a mistake with the partial index. Anyway why are you trying to avoid repositories? Because Doctrine is built that way using the repository pattern.